# Java Garbage collection against Local and Global variable with Thread Safe

Tags: java, garbage-collection, thread-safety, global-variables, local-variables

Which of the below snip of code is more Garbage Collection efficient in terms of TIME

```
Class Test{...}
```

**Local Variable**

```
private void function(){
   Test test = new Test();
    ....
}
```

**Global Variable**

```
Test test = null; 
private void function(){   
   if(test == null){
     test = new Test();   
   } 
}
```

> Let assume function() call frequently

**EDIT**

You all are good. Answered well.
Now I come to a point that

> CASE-1 is more GC efficient than CASE-2 but on the other hand CASE-1
>   is not thread safe. So both having pros and cons

.

Comment: I'd be more worried about the side-effects of having a "global variable" (looks like instance field to me). Such as loss of thread-safety.

Comment: The **Global Variable** scenario uses lazy-loading, which would avoid constantly reinstantiaing `test` every time that `function()` gets called.  This would also minimize the work done by the garbage collector.  On the downside, you would be stuck with an instance of `Test` in tenured memory, which would be a waste were the instance not being used often.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - can you elaborate?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know Memory and Performance both are contrary. Anyway you gave the answer that CASE-2 is more GC effeicient. Thanks!

Comment: @AmitYadav -   The interesting point is, the case where GC doesn't happen is more efficient in terms of *time* but less efficient in terms of *memory*.. You will have to specify *efficiency* in terms of what?

Comment: @AmitYadav - In that case the answer is case-2 as there will be less GC. *deleted my answer* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case 1 a Test is created and becomes eligible for GC on each call and this creates lots of garbage. In case 2 it's created once and is possibly never GCed.

Why we dont always use option 2 - it may be not thread safe. Let's replace Test with SimpleDateFormat and function() will need synchronization or it will not work in multi-threaded app. Synchronization is expensive too. So we need to decide which option is better a new object each time or syncronization.

Answer (score 1):

If the constructor has a side effect, your two options do two different things.

---

If `Test` carries state, Option 1 and Option 2 may not be equivalent anymore, either (and Option 2 may not be thread-safe).

Case in point: Many people make the mistake of using Java's date or number format objects like Option 2. That does not work well, as those are not threadsafe.

---

Assuming that `Test` is completely stateless and calling the constructor has no side effects (both of which you seem to imply), how about option 3:

```
private static final Test test = new Test();

private void function(){
    .....
}
```

No GC activity at all.

---

Or, if `Test` does carry state or is somehow not thread-safe, and you want to call `function` in a tight loop, Option 4:

```
private void function(Test test){
}

void theCaller(){
    Test test = new Test();
    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
       function(test);
    }
}
```

Since the method is `private` you are free to move to a less convenient way to invoke it in the name of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on the functions use and what the object is being defined to do in the problem set. I would always say, only create the object when you need to. There is no reason to have an object sitting around not being used. If you are planning to use that object outside of your function, you will want it initialized to null globally first, and then create the object when needed.

You shouldn't worry about Java's Garbage Collection efficiency. It's efficient. Just as long as you are not making 100s upon 100s and more of Objects dynamically constantly, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: .@James Combs this is simple illustration in real time function() call frequently. We know GC is very efficient but than again I would like to know which one is good practice to avoid GC call ?

Comment: Check the answer provided from @Thilo